# Does a full node attempt to remove tx from a valid block that shares the same parent?

Tags: bitcoin-core

If a full node receives A-B-C with C being a valid block and removes the transactions from the mempool, what happens if the next block is A-B-D? It is my understanding that the full node validates the D block and then if it’s valid hangs on to it until the blocks are reconciled? My question is does the full node try to remove the tx in D from the mempool as well? Since it is likely that C and D share some of the same txs what happens when the node attempts to delete a transaction in D, that was in C from the mempool?

Comment: A node wouldn’t switch to D unless there was E on top of it as well. Equal proof of work isn’t enough to cause a reorganisation, more work is.

Comment: Right, I left out the reorg to make it simpler, so let's say the next block after A-B-C is A-B-D-E, same question applies.